# Probability that neighbouring slots are empty

Tags: probability, combinations

There are $27$ slots for parking a car. A person parks his car in one of them except the end slots.  An hour after parking the car he returns to the parking lot to find that twelve slots are still occupied.  What is the probability that his neighbouring slots are empty?

My approach was if there are $27$ slots and $1$ of them is taken up by the man then there are $26$ left.  If we want the neighbours to be empty then the choices left for them are $24$.  If there are a total of $12$ cars including his own car then the $11$ remaining cars choose from $24$ spots.
The probability becomes $$\frac {\binom {24}{11}}{\binom {26}{11}}$$
It comes out to be $$\frac {21}{65}$$
Is it correct?

Comment: In real life, people may prefer to park where both adjacent slots are empty.  So you are assuming this is not the case and slots are taken independently of existing parked cars

Comment: Yes there is non liking for a particular slot

Comment: If that is true, why would anyone care about the probability being asked for here?

Answer (score 2):

Making the assumption spelled out by Henry, your answer is correct, though I haven't encountered your notation for a combination, I would write $\frac{\binom{24}{11}}{\binom{26}{11}}$

Your approach is fine, sort of "standard", but here is another one.

There are $15$ vacant slots among the $26$ excluding yours. Imagine that they are $15$ "ghost cars", and you want $2$ of these ghost cars in the $2$ slots adjoining you, $Pr = \frac{15}{26}\frac{14}{25}= \frac{21}{65}$

Comment: That's a creative (and amusing) way to confirm the solution.

Comment: Yes i have edited it now.thanx for pointing it out

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Thanks, the fun lies in trying out different things :)